# Entity Framework User and Role Management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a Visual Studio solution which contains several projects :

1. Domain classes
2. Data access layer - which contains DB context
3. MVC application.

The MVC application by default uses existing classes for user management and it also has his own ApplicationDbContext. In this case we have two DB contexts.

What is your experience regarding the user management ? Would it be better if I create my own classes for user management and place them to the Domain Classes project. I think it would be much easier latter for maintaining and in this case there will be only one DBContext. Another possible problem can be relations between existing ApplicationUsers(from the MVC project model) and classes from the Domain Classes Project. Or maybe to move the ApplicationUser class definition to the DomainClasses project ?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot). You have the option of using its built in UserAccount or using your own.

On a side note Brock is part of [Thinktecture](http://www.thinktecture.com/identityAndAccessControl). In one of the asp.net stand-ups it was mentioned that the team may just recommend a 3rd-party identity provider instead of role their own. That was my understanding but maybe I am just being hopeful. I think it was this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMTd5yS-yFE&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=2 but don't hold me to that.